# Laravel can't access object in blade when variable in where/find

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I try to ech the object of a laravel many-to-many relation in blade:

When I try to find the created_at with $product->id=47 and echo it out like so:

```
{{ $inquiry->products->find($product->id)->created_at }}
```

I get the error: *"Trying to get property 'created_at' of non-object..."*

When I remove the $product->id and change it to "47" everything works find:

```
{{ $inquiry->products->find(47)->created_at }}
```

But I need to query with the variable $product->id.

Any ideas what's wrong here?

Here is a longer part of my code:

```
@foreach ($upgrades as $upgrade)
  {{ $upgrade->id }} //Echos exactly as 47
//List all upgrades
 <select>
 @if($inquiry->products->where('id', $upgrade->id)->count() == 1)
    <option> {{ $inquiry->products->find($upgrade->id)->pivot->duration }}
 @endif
</select>
@endforeach
```

Comment: The strange thing is *$product->id* is *47*. I even can echo $upgrade->products->find($product->id) which gives mit the correct object. I only can't access that object value in blade. Same with where instead of find.

Comment: @TimLewis `find` on a Eloquent collection finds the model by its primary key ... but as you mentioned before this seems like it is probably being done in a loop or the result of a loop or something

Comment: Also, if you already have `$product`, why do you need to query it again? Can't you just use `$product->created_at`? Or are you trying to get the `created_at` of the pivot table? (Assuming it has one)

Comment: @lagbox True; I always forget about Eloquent Collection vs generic Collection; local tests show that `$model->relation->find(...)` is indeed equivalent to `$model->relation()->where(...)->first()`. @lukaskomar you'll need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73024719/edit) and include more detail;  there's some unknowns and we're guessing at this point

Comment: Thanks for your help @tim. I've tried your solution before. Same thing. When I hardcode *$product->id* as *47* everything works fine. When i replace it with *$product->id* I get the same error. And I'm aware that everything breaks when nothing is found with first() and find().

Comment: Yeah sorry, case of the Mondays on that code; it's equivalent. So once again, is this code used in a loop, for example: `foreach($inquiries as $inquiry)` (or similar), where `$product->id` could be different? If you're getting the result by hardcoding `47`, then it's obvious that `$product->id` _does not = 47_.

Comment: `@foreach ($upgrades as $upgrade)  {{ $upgrade->id }} // Echos exactly as 47` <- That `// Echos exactly as 47` is only true on the first iteration of your `foreach()` loop; on the next one, `$upgrade->id` is probably not going to be 47... Remove everything after `{{ $upgrade->id }}` and let the page render; you'll probably see `47, 48, 49` (etc.) (or, even easier, `{{ dd($upgrades->pluck('id')) }}` before your `foreach()` loop)